# How to create global constant variables in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm searching for a way to create a global constant variable, which I can use in my controllers.

I've totally no idea how to create that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I find that there was no dignified response...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Very comfortable way is to use **Strongly-Typed Settings** for that.
You can access to these variables everywhere in a project and change its values without recompilation.

You can use Visual Studio editor to define settings (*Project > Properties > Settings)*:

[image: Settings VS Editor]

These variables will be added to an appropriate section in a *Web.config* or *App.config* file in this way:

```
<setting name="SomeStringVariable" serializeAs="String">
   <value>SomeStringValue</value>
</setting>
<setting name="SomeBoolVariable" serializeAs="String">
   <value>false</value>
</setting>
<setting name="SomeDoubleVariable" serializeAs="String">
   <value>1.23</value>
</setting>
```

You can use defined variables anywhere in your project in a simple way:

```
string myStringVariable = Settings.Default.SomeStringVariable;
bool myBoolVarialbe = Settings.Default.SomeBoolVariable;
double myDoubleVariable = Settings.Default.SomeDoubleVariable;
```

Comment: Thanks, this way is very nice!

Comment: What is more, you can add the settings file to some subfolder in your application - just to create dedicated settings for some part of your application (like Controllers).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Used it in my project. Absolutely awesome.

Answer (score 13):

1:
generate a static class(say Constant.cs)

set the property as

```
public static string YourConstant{
get { return "YourConstantValue";}}
```

accesses it anywhere

```
Constant.YourConstant;
```

or
2. you can also use web.config

```
<appSettings><add key="YourConstant" value="YourConstantValue" /></appSettings>
```

Use it as

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourConstant"];
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option is very useful!